# lsusb to /dev (webcam)

Tags: cygwin, webcam, lsusb

I plugin a webcam.  I could see new device with command lsusb

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 023: ID eb1a:2571 Web Cam
```

But I cannot see any new device in /dev

I tested with different webcam and got same issue, so confirmed the problem NOT due to webcam.
Besides, I am "root", so I have right to access any port.

How to map the webcam to /dev manually?

P.S. my platform is cygwin